# Is it possible to trace auxiliary functions in the Ocaml REPL

Tags: ocaml, trace, ocaml-toplevel

What I would like to do is trace the function `aux` that has restricted scope in a definition like:

```
let example = function 
  arg -> 
    let rec aux =  
      (* some recursive function body*)  
    in 
    aux arg 
;;
```

with `#trace` or a similar toplevel command, so that the trace appears when `example` is called.

(without just copy-pasting the auxiliary function under some other name and passing it to the toplevel)

note: I am using tuareg mode on emacs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In the toplevel, you can trace only toplevel functions.